# How to show datepicker only on icon click using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am facing one issue. I need to display the jquery datepicker only on icon click. I am explaining my code below.

```
<input type="text" class="inputType2" id="car_d_date" value="">
<span class="globalcolor" id="calicon">
  <i class="icon-calendar-7"></i>
</span>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $("#car_d_date").datepicker();
  $("#calicon").click(function(){
    $("#car_d_date").datepicker('show');
  })
})
```

In my case also input field click the calender is showing. Here I need when user will click on calender icon then the calender will display and selected date will viewed on the textbox.

Comment: hide the date picker after initialization. `$("#car_d_date").datepicker('hide');`

Comment: $("#car_d_date").datepicker("show"); Try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value of `showOn` attribute of datepicker to empty.

```js
$("#car_d_date").datepicker({
  showOn: ''
});
$("#calicon").click(function(){
  $("#car_d_date").datepicker('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" class="inputType2" id="car_d_date" value="">
<span class="globalcolor" id="calicon">
  <i class="icon-calendar-7">icon</i>
</span>
```

Comment: Brother, better if it get closed on clicking again.

Comment: @WC2 It can be done by simple code but datepicker does not do this as default. When you  click on input datepicker only showing and when click again it also showing and it does not closed

Comment: for toggle effect on icon click  `var i = 0;
$("#calicon").click(function(){
console.log(i);
if(i == 0){
$("#car_d_date").datepicker('show');
i++;
}
else
{
$("#car_d_date").datepicker('hide');
i--;
}
});
`